# How can i use when, then, otherwise to conditonally replace row values in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a data set with three columns. Column A is to be checked for containing parts of strings. If the string matches foo partwise, the value from L should be replaced by the value of column G. If not nothing should change. For this I have tried the following.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "A": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg",],
            "L": ["A54", "A12", "B84", "C12"],
            "G": ["X34", "C84", "G96", "L6",],
        }
    )
print(df)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ foo1 ┆ A54 ┆ X34 │
│ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
│ foo2 ┆ B84 ┆ G96 │
│ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L6  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘

expected outcome

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ foo1 ┆ X34 ┆ X34 │
│ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
│ foo2 ┆ G96 ┆ G96 │
│ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L6  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I tried this

```
df = df.with_columns(
            pl.when(
                pl.col("A")
                .str.contains("foo"))
            .then(pl.col("L"))
            .alias("G")
            .otherwise(pl.col("G"))
        )
```

However, this does not work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1. The alias always goes at the end.
2. The order of operations often puts the `alias` in the `otherwise` so that the `then` doesn't get an `alias` leading to unexpected results.  As a result I always wrap everything in parenthesis before an `alias` even though this may not always be strictly necessary

As a result I think you want this:

```
df.with_columns(
            (pl.when(
                pl.col("A")
                .str.contains("foo"))
            .then(pl.col("G"))
            .otherwise(pl.col("L")))
            .alias("L")
        )
```

There's a new feature (I'm not sure which version is the first that can do this) but you can do this too:

```
df.with_columns(
            L=pl.when(
                pl.col("A")
                .str.contains("foo"))
            .then(pl.col("G"))
            .otherwise(pl.col("L"))
        )
```

Comment: I get your solution but i guess you mixed up L and G. Thank you!

Comment: @Horseman oops, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("A").str.contains("foo"))\
        .then(pl.col("G"))\
        .otherwise(pl.col("L")).alias("L")
)
```